# Bathroom faucet handles no screw or cap to remove. Help

Tags: plumbing

[image]

I need to stop this faucet from leaking. I can't get the handle off. There's no set screw and no cap. I've tried prying it and pulling straight up. Anyone that can help please tell me.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a cap on this?  From the photo it appears the very top may be removable.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A close-up of that cap might be helpful. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

The top of the faucet handle is probably a cap that covers the screw that holds the handle in place. See if you can can get under the lip of the cap (just before the top decorative curve) and pop it off. A putty knife or similar would work.

Answer (score 1):

the cap on the top of the decorative rings unthreads counter clockwise ...grip handle at rings to keep steady and unthread...maybe tight if not removed recently...use thin rbr gloves for grip...do not use a wrench

Answer (score 0):

Try a small flat head screwdriver to pop it off. I agree, it looks like the top comes off. If your certain it doesn’t come off, check underneath, sometimes it’s attached from the underside with a threaded nut